# Swift show and hide activity indicator on func with dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, task

I have a function that makes a call and waits for a response from a server. I would like to show the activity indicator before a request and hide it after the answer to this same function. Why? To avoid code repetition. I will have calls to the server in other actions.

It works the way it is right now: manually calling the start and stop animation on the login button.

To test the indicator, I added sleep on the server.

**Question: How can I show/hide the indicator for every call to the server?**

*Button on login view:*

```
@IBAction func btnLog2(_ sender: Any) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        customActivityIndicatory(self.view, startAnimate: true)
    })

    let user = User(email: login_email.text!, password : login_password.text!)

    var jsonData = Data()
    let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(user)
    }
    catch {
    }

    makeRequestPost(endpoint: "http://blog.local:4711/api/login",
                    requestType: "POST",
                    requestBody: jsonData,
                    completionHandler: { (response : ApiContainer<Login>?, error : Error?) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("error calling POST on /todos")
                            print(error)
                            return
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                            customActivityIndicatory(self.view, startAnimate: false)
                        })

                        let a = (response?.result[0])!
                        let b = (response?.meta)!

                        if(b.sucess == "yes") {
                            DAKeychain.shared["email"] = (user.email) // Store
                            DAKeychain.shared["token"] = (a.token) // Store
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarClients") as UIViewController

                                self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
                            })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid E-mail or Password", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                                myAlert.addAction(okAction)

                                self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            })
                        }
    } )


}
```

*request func*

```
func makeRequestPost<T>(endpoint: String,
                    requestType: String = "GET",
                    requestBody: Data,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ()) {

guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
    print("Error: cannot create URL")
    let error = BackendError.urlError(reason: "Could not create URL")
    completionHandler(nil, error)
    return
}

var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession.shared
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.httpBody = requestBody
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        completionHandler(nil, error)
        return
    }
    guard error == nil else {
        completionHandler(nil, error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiContainer<T>.self, from: responseData)
        completionHandler(response, nil)
    }
    catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }

})
task.resume()
```

}

*function on helper file:*

```
func makeRequestPost<T>(endpoint: String,
                    requestType: String = "GET",
                    requestBody: Data,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ()) {

guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
    print("Error: cannot create URL")
    let error = BackendError.urlError(reason: "Could not create URL")
    completionHandler(nil, error)
    return
}

var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession.shared
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.httpBody = requestBody
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        completionHandler(nil, error)
        return
    }
    guard error == nil else {
        completionHandler(nil, error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiContainer<T>.self, from: responseData)
        completionHandler(response, nil)
    }
    catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }

})
task.resume()
```

}

**EDIT:**

I created a class CustomActivityIndicator, but the loader is not shown. Start and Stop are printed on the console.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class CustomActivityIndicator {

var viewContainer = UIView()
var startAnimate:Bool? = true
var mainContainer = UIView()
var activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
let viewBackgroundLoading = UIView()

init(viewContainer: UIView, startAnimate: Bool?) {
    self.viewContainer = viewContainer
    self.startAnimate = startAnimate
    setup()
}

func setup() {

    let mainContainer: UIView = UIView(frame: viewContainer.frame)
    mainContainer.center = viewContainer.center
    mainContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    mainContainer.alpha = 0.5
    mainContainer.tag = 789456123
    mainContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let viewBackgroundLoading: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 80,height: 80))
    viewBackgroundLoading.center = viewContainer.center
    viewBackgroundLoading.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    viewBackgroundLoading.alpha = 0.5
    viewBackgroundLoading.clipsToBounds = true
    viewBackgroundLoading.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    let activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicatorView.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y: 0.0,width: 40.0, height: 40.0)
    activityIndicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle =
        UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    activityIndicatorView.center = CGPoint(x: viewBackgroundLoading.frame.size.width / 2, y: viewBackgroundLoading.frame.size.height / 2)
}

func start(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        print("start")
        self.viewBackgroundLoading.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView)
        self.mainContainer.addSubview(self.viewBackgroundLoading)
        self.viewContainer.addSubview(self.mainContainer)
        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    })
}

func stop() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        print("stop")
        for subview in self.viewContainer.subviews {
            if subview.tag == 789456123{
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    })
}

}
```

Inside func makeRequestPost

```
func makeRequestPost<T>(endpoint: String,
                    requestType: String = "GET",
                    requestBody: Data,
                    activityIndicator: CustomActivityIndicator? = nil,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ()) {


activityIndicator?.start() .......
```

and on the action button:

```
let loading = CustomActivityIndicator(viewContainer: self.view, startAnimate: true)
    makeRequestPost(endpoint: "http://blog.local:4711/api/login",
                    requestType: "POST",
                    requestBody: jsonData,
                    activityIndicator: loading,
                    completionHandler: { (response : ApiContainer<Login>?, error : Error?) in
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading some tutorials, I ended up answering my own question.

**What did I do?**

1) I created a class: *ViewControllerUtils*

```
class ViewControllerUtils {

var container: UIView = UIView()
var loadingView: UIView = UIView()
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()

/*
 Show customized activity indicator,
 actually add activity indicator to passing view

 @param uiView - add activity indicator to this view
 */
func showActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {

    self.container.frame = uiView.frame
    self.container.center = uiView.center
    self.container.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.container.alpha = 0.7
    self.container.tag = 789456123

    loadingView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:80, height:80)
    loadingView.center = uiView.center
    loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    loadingView.clipsToBounds = true
    loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width:40.0, height:40.0);
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge
    activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x:loadingView.frame.size.width / 2, y:loadingView.frame.size.height / 2);

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
        self.container.addSubview(self.loadingView)
    uiView.addSubview(self.container)
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}

/*
 Hide activity indicator
 Actually remove activity indicator from its super view

 @param uiView - remove activity indicator from this view
 */
func hideActivityIndicator(uiView: UIView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let viewWithTag = uiView.viewWithTag(789456123) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    else {
        return
    }
    }
}

/*
 Define UIColor from hex value

 @param rgbValue - hex color value
 @param alpha - transparency level
 */
func UIColorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32, alpha:Double=1.0)->UIColor {
    let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
    let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
    let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0
    return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:CGFloat(alpha))
}

}
```

2) On *func makeRequestPost* I added a new param (view) and calls to start and stop the loading view

```
func makeRequestPost<T>(endpoint: String,
                    requestType: String = "GET",
                    requestBody: Data,
                    view: UIView,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ()) {

ViewControllerUtils().showActivityIndicator(uiView: view)

guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
    print("Error: cannot create URL")
    let error = BackendError.urlError(reason: "Could not create URL")
    completionHandler(nil, error)
    return
}

var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let session = URLSession.shared
urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.httpBody = requestBody
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in

    ViewControllerUtils().hideActivityIndicator(uiView: view)
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        completionHandler(nil, error)
        return
    }
    guard error == nil else {
        completionHandler(nil, error!)
        return
    }

    do {
        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(ApiContainer<T>.self, from: responseData)
        completionHandler(response, nil)
    }
    catch {
        print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
        print(error)
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }

})

task.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your **makeRequest** function is in separate service class, so basically you can add general onReqestStart on onRequestComplete blocks, and execute them whenever post **makeRequest** has been called.

Please take a look on https://cocoapods.org/pods/ResultPromises maybe you will find it helpful

**EDIT:**

It is bad idea to declare global functions end moreover expose them to entire module. You can end up with thousands helper functions and complexity of you project will increase exponentially. Although fews still protecting **Procedural** approach (when functions declared that way), community evolved from it in late 80s. So I strongly advice you to declare class to wrap all network related functions (NetworkClient/Service/Manager whatever)

Returning to you question: you can take you activity indicator as argument:

```
func makeRequestPost<T>(endpoint: String,
                    requestType: String = "GET",
                    requestBody: Data,
                    activityIndicator: CustomActivityIndicator?,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (ApiContainer<T>?, Error?) -> ())
```

So you can start it and complete it inside you function, instead of copy/pasting code any time you are using your function.

Comment: It is not a class yet. I added the helper function to my question.

Comment: Try to avoid keeping functions global. In this particular case you can create NetwrokService that can send requests and supply it with requestDidSent/DidComplete blocks, if any you are using same activity indicator all over the app.